# What does this ".children" attribute do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, keyword

I'm trying to understand a Key-Bigram extractor's working and I cannot understand what does the following block of code do.

[Here](https://github.com/AjayJohnAlex/Keyword-Extraction/blob/master/model.py) is the source code.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

string = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'


def textProcessing(doc):
    Words = []
    doc = nlp(doc)

    for possible_words in doc:
        Words.append([possible_words , [child for child in possible_words.children]])
    
    print(Words)

textProcessing(string)
```

Everything else is workin fine and I understood well, however I can not understand what `child for child in possible_words.children` does.

Comment: `children` is not mention anywhere else in the code. If think it may be just `[child for child in possible_nouns]` to get `"NOUN","PROPN"`

Comment: @TalhaTayyab each possible_noun is either a NOUN or a PROPER NOUN. Precisely put, I can not understand how is the list `possible_nouns.children` generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`token.children`](https://spacy.io/api/token#children) uses the dependency parse to get all tokens that directly depend on the token in question. In a visualization (try [displacy](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy)), this will be all the tokens with arrows pointing away from a token; if the word is a verb this could be the subject and any objects, if the word is a noun it could be any adjectives modifying it, for example.

Comment: This makes complete sense, I understand it now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know spacy's API very well, being a user of nltk ;)

But, simply put, as `possible_words` is a `Token`, its `children` property returns all tokens that sit in the syntactic unit of the parent token.

Therefore, `[child for child in possible_words.children]` turns the iterable returned by this property into a list.
I'd have written it `list(possible_words.children)`, though.

Comment: I could not find a precise theory for what a syntactic unit is. I ran the code above and recieved the following output: `[[1, []], [2, [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]], [3, []], [4, []], [5, []], [6, []], [7, []], [8, []], [9, [2, 8]]]`. I can see what list this has produced, but I cannot understand how did it produce it.

Comment: The code in your question should not give that output. It looks like you converted tokens (which the code would output) into token indices somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

looks like it's a class in Python and children is an element of the "possible_word" variable stored in "spacy" file